# how can i get the data from dotnet web-services in android?

Tags: android, .net, web-services

I am new to web-services. i have save my data in web-services but i doesn't know how to get that data from web-services. my web-services in .net in that web-services i have use SOAP parsing. so please help me how can i get the data from  url.i have search in google but i didn't find the solution.

i have use the following code for save my data into webservice..

```
package com.soap;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyworldActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name,uname,pass,num,mail,img;
    Button save,back;




    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost/service1/InsertUsertRegistrationDetails";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "InsertUsertRegistrationDetails";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost/service1";
    private static final String URL = "http://113.193.181.53/MyWorldApp/Service1.asmx";

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
        mail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mail);
        img = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.img);
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();

            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                call();

            }

        });


    }

    public void call()
    {
        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("Name", name.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("UserName", uname.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("Password", pass.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("MobileNumber", num.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("EmailID", mail.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("image",img.getText().toString());
            Log.e("success","success");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

            tv.setText(result.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i get the data from dotnet web-services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good lord. Where do I begin? Firstly, I would take down your (very) public website and work locally until you actually have something complete. Secondly, from the code it looks like you're passing names, mobile phone numbers, passwords and emails in plain across an unencrypted link. If you don't know why you shouldn't do this, then learn (or find a different day job).

Comment: Also, never make network calls on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SOAP requests, u can make use of HTTP request/response.

Please see the below sample code:

```
    /**
 * Connects to server. Sends data to server. Receive data from server.
 * 
 * @param request
 *            IN parameter. Request string.
 * @param response
 *            OUT parameter, to get data which receives from server.
 * @param error
 *            OUT parameter, to get error information.
 * @return - Function status, true or false.
 */
private boolean requestData(URI uri, StringBuilder responseString, StringBuilder error) {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    boolean isSuccess = true;
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        response = httpClient.execute(request);         

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        error.append(e.getMessage());
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "httpClient.execute() ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        isSuccess = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error.append(e.getMessage());
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "httpClient.execute() IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Server connection is not OK.
        TrendDataMgr.getInstance().setConnectionStatus(false);
        isSuccess = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error.append(e.getMessage());
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "httpClient.execute() Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        isSuccess = false;
    }

    // If response not needed, Exit.
    if (null == responseString) {
        return isSuccess;
    }

    if (response == null) {
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "requestData().httpClient.execute() failed. Response = null");
        return false;
    }

    // Server connection is OK.

    try {
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        responseString.append(str);
        //Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "httpClient.execute()" + str);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        error.append(e.getMessage());
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "EntityUtils.toString(), Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        isSuccess = false;
    } 
    return isSuccess;

}
```

U can call this function using the URL:

```
String request = URL + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(parameter, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
boolean isSuccess = true;
URI uri = new URI(request);
isSuccess =  requestData(uri, response, error);
```

Hope this helps u.